# Except method returns all the members instead of returning only the different ones

Tags: c#, winforms

In the following snippet of code, the Except method returns just all members of the list A instead of the ones which exists in A and not in B!

```
List<Process> ListA = new List<Process>();
List<Process> ListB = new List<Process>();
var ListC = ListA.Except(ListB).ToList();
```

ListC will get everything that exists inside ListA, without taking ListB into account at all!
What is wrong here?
Some information to be noted: ListB is a copy of `ListA`, with this rule that `ListB` remains intact but `ListA` gets Updated, and the idea is to get only those processes that are run since `ListB` is being initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Except` uses the default equality comparer, which by default uses the `Object.Equals()` method, which by default checks for reference equality.

Do you consider two `Process` objects to be equivalent even if they are two different objects (e.g. two different objects having the same Id?)

The easiest way to solve it is to override `Object.Equals(object obj)` in your `Process` class to use whatever equivalence you have. When implementing `Object.Equals()` you should also implement `GetHashCode()` so that it returns the same code for any two objects that are equivalent according to the `Equals()` implementation.

Comment: Should i use an extension method to override equals? since i dont have a class for this? i am just using it inside a method to get the new processes.

Comment: No, you cannot use an extension method. If you can't modify the `Process` class you can use the overload of [`Except()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a custom comparer as an argument.

Comment: Thank you very much ;) So the first approach is to inherit from process class and override its Equals and GetHashCode methods and use my inherited class :) and if i dont want the hassle, i can use the later approach :) 
Thanks again :)

Comment: It looks like much more hassle to inherit from a class like that than to build a simple comparer.

Comment: @AndersAbel: I tried this :http://pastebin.com/0s84hKdc but  it still doesnt work, what am i missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm willing to bet you're not implementing `Equals` correctly. Can you show your custom implementation?

As you can see, it should work just fine:

```
void Main()
{
    List<int> ListA = new List<int> { 5, 9 };
    List<int> ListB = new List<int> {3, 5 };
    var ListC = ListA.Except(ListB).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine (ListC);
}
```

Output

> 9